# Mac with Rails & Postgres Installed - Overheats quickly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, mac, postgresql

Anyone else have this problem? I'm on a 15" Macbook running rails and postgres. Needless to say, shortly after powering up the mac and getting into development work, the mac gets very hot at the bottom back left of the laptop.

Anyone else experience this and have any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

That's typical on a Macbook; the power supply is at the back-left corner.

It's nothing to do with Rails or Postgre. Just try watching a video on YouTube or playing a 3D-heavy game. You'll fry your left knee!

My preferred solutions are as follows:

1. Sit the Macbook on a table.
2. Put a large book (world atlas) between the Macbook and my flesh.

Answer (score 1):

Download [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/?p=134) and set the cooler fan speeds to 2000 RPM by default or maybe a bit more if you don't mind the noise.

This keeps the Macbook much cooler, even the spots above the keyboard are much cooler afterwoods. Also the Fans don't spin up as often as before.

I also do a lot of developing and always hated the fan spin ups and heat while running tests, this really solved my problem!